# How to get last Week's date in bash SunOS

Tags: bash, date, sunos

Here is my issue: I have a backup bash script that needs to access a folder with a date in its name for example : backup_01072022 .

I used `` date=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%d%m%Y` ``  when i needed to access the backup folder of yesterday.

Now I want to access the backup folder of last week :

`` date=`TZ=GMT+168 date +%d%m%Y` ``  , it doesn't work , it show today's date.

I read that TZ doesn't work for a value above +144.

Is there any other way of manipulating dates in **SunOS 6.8** ?

**Notes :**

SunOS 6.8

version of the `date` util : 8.5

version of bash : 4.1.11(2)-release

Comment: Adjusting the timezone seems like a hack, at best, for getting times in the past.

Comment: SunOS or Solaris and which version?

Comment: BTW, next time you're designing this, `%Y%m%d` is a much better format -- ensures that ANSI sort order and date sort order are one and the same.

Comment: Anyhow -- do you have Python on this system? (SunOS provides a lot less than modern Linux does for good shell-accessible date manipulation tools).

Comment: ...also, which version of bash? Is it new enough to support `printf %(...)T` for converting seconds-since-epoch to arbitrary date formats?

Comment: Show output of `/usr/gnu/bin/date --version | head -n 1`.

Comment: SunOS 6.8 , version of the date util : 8.5  , version of bash 4.1.11(2)-release  .

Comment: That sounds like you have GNU date. So use `/usr/gnu/bin/date` explicitly instead of just `date` and you should have `-d`/`--date` available

Comment: So when I'm not specifying, what `date util` am I using if not the `GNU date` ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/rJMFxIbDe-g looks like a good tutorial on `PATH` (it discusses bash and linux but general principles are similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful commments and answers I was able to make it work using :

```
/usr/gnu/bin/date -d "last week" '+%d%m%Y'
```

It turns out I was not using the `GNU date` util until I specified it explicitly, and that's neither `--date` nor `-d`  was working for me.
I still can't figure out what date util I was using by default if not `GNU date`.

Comment: `which date` or `type date` should tell you which `date` you were using (it should match up with the first `date` found when searching through the directories listed in the `PATH` variable); try `PATH=/usr/gnu/bin:"${PATH}"` and then run your new `date` command (sans the full path) ... it should still work since `/usr/gnu/bin` is now the first directory checked in `PATH`

Comment: You appear to have copied one of the scripts from [@markp-fuso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72886582/1745001), posted it as your own answer, and then accepted it. Please don't do that, just accept the original answer.

Answer (score 2):

This'll depend on the version of `date` on your system.

With `GNU date` (v 8.26):

```
$ TZ=GMT date '+%d%m%Y'
06072022                        # today

$ TZ=GMT date '+%d%m%Y' -d 'last week'
29062022

$ TZ=GMT date '+%d%m%Y' -d '7 days ago'
29062022
```

**NOTE:** I'll leave it up to OP to determine if the explicit `TZ` setting should be adjusted (or used at all)

Comment: I don't think either SunOS or Solaris comes with GNU `date` at all.

Comment: @markp-fuso both answers show today's date. It's weird since my system's `GNU date` version shows 8.5.

Comment: solaris comes with several date commands. you may not be invoking GNU date if you aren't specifying the full path: `which date` / `type date` / etc to check

Comment: @MohamedDouzi v 8.5 should be sufficient; as others have pointed out in comments when  you run `date` you may not be accessing `GNU date`; find the full path of `GNU date` and then a) use that full path in place of `date` or b) make sure the directory (where `GNU date` is located) comes first in your `PATH` env variable

Answer (score 1):

I seem to recall SunOS comes with Perl, so if you don't have a `date` that supports `--date="..."`, you should be able to do:

```
date=$(perl -MPOSIX -e '
    print POSIX::strftime "%d%m%Y", localtime time-(60*60*24*7)
')
```

Comment: You're right my system's `date` doesn't support `--date` nor the option `-d` for some reason.

Comment: This works Thank you. I'm still gonna check what does it exactly do before I implement it in my script.

Comment: `perldoc` is your friend (`perldoc POSIX` ; `perldoc -f localtime`;  etc)